# Timeline Google Chart, agregar slider/picker

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, google-visualization

**¿Existe alguna manera de insertarle a un TimeLine un picker o slider para capturar el instante?**
Ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Yo debería actualizar parametros a partir de la fecha seleccionada con el picker.

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'President' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'President' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });

     dataTable.addRows([
        [ 'machine1', 'WORK', new Date(0,0,0,14,0,0), new Date(0,0,0,15,0,0)],
        [ 'machine2', 'ALARMA', new Date(0,0,0,15,0,0), new Date(0,0,0,16,0,0)]]);
        
    var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
      selection = chart.getSelection();
      if (selection.length > 0) {
        console.log(dataTable.getValue(selection[0].row, 0));
      }
    });

    chart.draw(dataTable);
  },
  packages: ['timeline']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="timeline"></div>
```

Answer (score 13):

Esta solución no sé si te va a gustar porque es un poco *hacky* y no usa los comandos normales de Google Chart o los timelines (los usa pero para calcular valores secundarios que se usarán luego).

La idea es la siguiente:

- Poner el timeline en un contenedor
- Crear una barra dentro de ese contenedor
- Crear un evento cuando se mueve el ratón encima del contenedor, para mover la barra horizontalmente a la posición del ratón (esto realmente es cosmético).
- Crear un evento que cuando se pulse el ratón (ojo: mouseclick y no click para evitar problemas con los eventos del chart) realice una simple regla de tres para calcular la fecha-hora que corresponde a esa zona del timeline.

Aquí puedes verlo funcionando:

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'President' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'President' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });

     dataTable.addRows([
        [ 'machine1', 'WORK', new Date(0,0,0,14,0,0), new Date(0,0,0,15,0,0)],
        [ 'machine2', 'ALARMA', new Date(0,0,0,15,0,0), new Date(0,0,0,16,0,0)]]);
        
    var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
      selection = chart.getSelection();
      if (selection.length > 0) {
        console.log(dataTable.getValue(selection[0].row, 0));
      }
    });

   var options = {
          hAxis: {
            minValue: new Date(0,0,0,14,0,0),
            maxValue: new Date(0,0,0,16,0,0)
          }
        };
        
    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
    
    // una vez dibujado el timeline, leemos el SVG
    svg = document.querySelector("#timeline svg"); 
    // calculamos los tamaños que debe tener la barra
    var sizes = svg.querySelector("g:first-of-type path:first-of-type").getAttribute("d").split(",");
    bar.style.height = (2*sizes[sizes.length-1])  + "px";
    // y otros valores que nos ayudarán a calcular la nueva fecha más tarde
    min = parseInt(sizes[0].substr(1));
    totalTime = options.hAxis.maxValue - options.hAxis.minValue;
    lengthTime = svg.getAttribute("width") - min;
    initialDate = options.hAxis.minValue;

  },
  packages: ['timeline']
});


// las variables que vamos a usar
var timelineContainer = document.getElementById("timeline-container");
var bar = document.getElementById("bar");
var svg = document.querySelector("#timeline svg");
var offsetLeft = timelineContainer.getBoundingClientRect().left;
var min = 0;
var totalTime = 0;
var lengthTime = 0;

// cuando se mueva el ratón sobre el timeline: mover la barra
timelineContainer.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  var newValue = (e.clientX - offsetLeft);
  if (newValue >= min) {
   bar.style.left = newValue + "px";
   bar.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    bar.style.display = "none";
  }  
});

// cuando se pulse en el timeline: calcular fecha correspondiente a la posición pulsada
timelineContainer.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
  
  // leemos la posición pulsada
  var currentPosition = e.clientX - offsetLeft - min;
  // calculamos el tiempo transcurrido con una regla de tres
  var currentTime = Math.floor(currentPosition * totalTime / lengthTime);
  // añadimos ese tiempo a la fecha/hora inicial
  var dateClicked = new Date(initialDate.getTime() + currentTime);
  
  // Aquí puedes hacer las operaciones que quieras con la nueva fecha
  console.log(dateClicked);
  
});
```

```css
#timeline-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
}

#bar {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid red;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#timeline-container:hover #bar {
  display: block;
}

#bar::before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 0px;
  border:10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid red;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<div id="timeline-container">
  <div id="timeline"></div>
  <div id="bar">
</div>
```

Comment: Perdón por tardar, es muy bueno lo que propones realmente, es lo más aproximado que pude encontrar y hacer. Me gustaría ver otras propuestas de igual manera.

Comment: @nawelittle no te preocupes. A ver si tienes suerte y alguien se anima a poner otra respuesta. Si nadie lo hace antes del viernes, yo pondré otra recompensa en la pregunta.